# Disable HTML stack traces by Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, mod-php

The administrator has installed Xdebug 2.1.1 in our shared PHP 5.3.0 server in order to use its debugger. Now, I can hardly read the stack traces of uncatched exceptions because they are formatted by Xdebug with annoying colours that interact badly with the site's CSS:

[image: Unreadable stack trace]

Since PHP runs as Apache module, I've tried to disable this feature in an `.htaccess` file but I can't make it go:

```
php_flag xdebug.default_enable Off
php_flag xdebug.overload_var_dump Off
php_flag xdebug.show_exception_trace Off
php_value xdebug.trace_format 1
```

`phpinfo()` shows my changes in the *Local Value* column but I can still see those horrible orange tables. What's the directive I need to change?

Comment: http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check for [`xdebug_disable()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214153020/https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_disable):

> *Disables stack traces*
>
> Disable showing stack traces on error conditions.

See as well [`xdebug.default_enable`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214153020/https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#default_enable):

> ###### boolean xdebug.default_enable = true
>
> If this setting is 1, then stacktraces will be shown by default on an error event. You can disable showing stacktraces from your code with **[xdebug_disable()](https://web.archive.org/web/20200214153020/https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_disable)**. As this is one of the basic functions of Xdebug, it is advisable to leave this setting set to 1.

Comment: `xdebug.default_enable` has no apparent effect, but calling `xdebug_disable()` on top of my code works fine. I'll see how to pack it in my web site settings.

Comment: Try to put `xdebug.default_enable` into the system's php.ini, maybe that works. Additionally probably using `0` instead of `off` in the .htaccess configuration might also help, but that's just an assumption, I have not tested it.

Comment: Alright... I've done further testing and the directive *is* `xdebug.default_enable` but it seems there's a bug somewhere: in the shared development server it's ignored, in my local installation its fully honoured.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Are you still using the .htaccess configuration method or are you using php.ini? Just asking for clarification.

Comment: Just tried `.htaccess` (being a shared resouce, I don't want to disturb others). It's worth nothing that phpinfo() reports the directive as changed in all cases. I wrote a quick workaround with `auto_prepend_file` that works for me.

Comment: I was close to suggest auto prepend file as well, however I really wonder why the .htaccess rules do not properly work. Maybe it's a mod_php issue or something.

Comment: xdebug.default_enable=off in php.ini worked with php5.4 on debian

Answer (score 14):

You need to make sure you have `html_errors=0` in PHP as well.
Also, orange isn't horrible ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. I already use HTML errors, together with `error_prepend_string` and `error_append_string` so I can display line feeds. If I disable it, Xdebug does not draw HTML but that makes the error unreadable as well because everything's in a single line. I don't want to search for error messages in the *View Source* window...

Comment: Very useful if you are outputting json from PHP for use with Javascript, angular, and that all.

Comment: If @derick answers you had better listen. He wrote XDebug.

Answer (score 6):

Add following code in the initialization Script:

```
 if (function_exists('xdebug_disable')) {
           xdebug_disable();
         }
```

Comment: Like Alvaro said, Option #2 here has nothing to do with displaying the HTML stack trace.

Comment: Updated as per suggestion.