# Since upgrade to php 5.3 php -i output is in html format

Tags: php, diagnostics

Just a minor niggle, but is there a way to get the old plain text formatted output from

```
php -i
```

Since **v5.3** it seems to output everything in html format which is a mess from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should disable xdebug and set the `html_errors` parameter in your **php.ini** to `0`. I think this should work.

```
html_errors=0
```

[Disable HTML stack traces by Xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911897/disable-html-stack-traces-by-xdebug)